# Reflect changes to objects in a relationship in parent object with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two entities event and time. The event entity has a 1 to many relationship to time entities as each event can be performed multiple times. Now I want to display all the events chronologically in a tableView. So I set up a fetchedResultsController to fetch all time objects, sort them according to the start time and display the event information by using the relationship to the event object. So far so good. But now if the user tabs an entry in the table I pass an event object to the detailViewController where the event can be edited.

The problem is that now only the event entity is marked as updated. I found this out by looking at the userInfo directory of the NSManagedObjectDidChange notification. In consequence the delegate methods on the FRC are not fired as no time objects have been changed.

How can I manually mark a time object as changed to make the FRC recognize the changes and update the cells accordingly? I tried firing the KVO methods `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` but it did not work so far.

Thanks alot
Thomas

Comment: What I now tried is posting manually NSManagedObjectContextObjectDidChangeNotifications with a new userInfo dictionary in which I included the time objects which are affected by the change of the event objects. Unfortunately the FRC does not react.

Comment: Currently I am working through an issue where I want to sort in view based on the value of a property in a relationship, and my below solution isn't quite enough. Good luck! FRCs are always a headache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My model is a little different, but it can easily be translated to your one.
I got a tree-like structure:

- Element

  - title
  - parent (to-one)
- Folder : Element

  - children (to-many)
- File : Element

When a file gets added or deleted, only the first folder in the queue up gets notified about this change. When a file's title changes, not a single folder would get notified. So, what to do?
I tried overriding -willChangeValueForKey: and -didChangeValueForKey: in my Element class.

```
- (void)willChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [super willChangeValueForKey:key];
    [self.parent willChangeValueForKey:@"children"];
}

- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [super didChangeValueForKey:key];
    [self.parent didChangeValueForKey:@"children"];
}
```

Basically, what this does is forcing the parent folder to update because one of its children changed.
Hope it works for you, too.

Comment: This caused a bunch of crashes when I tested adding it to my app—use at your own risk.

Comment: FWIW: this appears to be the right idea, but it's best to not override those methods, instead calling them in whatever method you make the changes to the child object in, like this:

Comment: Apple's docs clearly state "You should not override this method in subclasses". From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/willChangeValueForKey:

Comment: Like mentioned above - not a good idea to override these methods. Can I suggest you update your answer with a similar but safer implementation? i.e. wrapping all element updates inside an update method.

Comment: @JordanSmith The whole point of overriding the 'setter' is to not have to worry about calling other methods to correctly propagate the change. Besides, having a single extra 'update' method would not suffice to correctly  send the notifications in will/did pairs.

Answer (score 5):

I'm working through some similar types of updates right now as well.  Here's the way I approached the problem.

Let's say we have object A, which relates to object B. B has a property C.  We want changes to property C to be reflected in FRCs that use A as the fetched object.  What I did to make this happen was to define an accessor to property C from object A:

```
//A.m
- (void)setC:(int)cValue {
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"b"];
  self.b.c = cValue
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"b"];
}

- (int)c {
  return self.b.c;
}
```

This allowed my cells to update based on FRC callbacks with type NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate.  Hopefully this helps solve your problem.

Comment: I am a bit confused. You define the setter of B's property in A? What do you think of using `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey` to set up the dependencies? Like it is done here http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/220109-nsset-keypathsforvaluesaffectingvalueforkey.html

Comment: B obviously has the ability to set it's property, but I added a property to set the property from A as well, for convenience.  It helps funnel access to the property in my case, but it may be completely different for you. Still, wherever you set the property, you should be able to use the will and did change.  I think that way of setting up dependencies is a good idea, but it just hasn't worked in practice for me.

Answer (score 5):

The answer above from @Jenox appears to be the right idea, but it's best to not override those methods as they're called whenever *any* key is changed on the child object and will probably impact performance and cause unexpected side-effects (it did for me). Probably best to just call them in whatever method you make the changes to the child object in, like this:

```
- (void)updateFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary {
    [myParentModel willChangeValueForKey:@"myChildObject"];
    [super updateFromDictionary:aDictionary];
    [myParentModel didChangeValueForKey:@"myChildObject"];
}
```

Note that `updateFromDictionary` is one of my methods, not a system method.

Comment: the world surely need the Swift for this!